# Program that is supposed to multiply & divide 2 numbers coming from user input

Tags: javascript, function, type-conversion

I converted both values coming from the user's input to numbers as you can see in my code, however, when I click the button to conduct the operation it returns NaN.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="#form">
  <p>1st Number: <input id="number1"></p>
  <p>2st Number: <input id="number2"></p>
  <button onclick="multiply()">Multiply</button>
   <button onclick="divide()">Divide</button>
  <br>
  <p id="result">The Result Is:</p>
</form>
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
const num1 = Number(document.getElementById("number1").value);
const num2 = Number(document.getElementById("number2").value);

  const multiply = function (num1, num2) {
      const result1 = num1 * num2;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result1;
  }
  
   const divide = function (num1, num2) {
    const result2 = num1 / num2;
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result2;
  }
```

Comment: You assign values to `num1` and `num2` just once before you enter anything.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not quite understand:/

Comment: The first two lines of your code will be executed immediately after your HTML is rendered. At that time both values will be empty - hence `NaN`.  These values will never be updated again.

Comment: Ah ok, that helped, now I know what you mean. I will try to fix it, thanks for the help.

Comment: Move the constants inside the function it should fix the issue.

Comment: I tried but it did not help. the problem is I am passing 2 arguments in, which should be the 2 input values. How can I dynamically update these 2 values? I put the variables inside the function, but it says "num1" has already been declared;

Comment: Eventually I get this error: "ReferenceError: multiply is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: here is the code: https://codepen.io/Nitrohide/pen/OJbZeEj

Comment: It works now. Solution? I deleted the form element and substituted it with <div> element. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method with jQuery

```
  <p>1st Number: <input id="number1"></p>
  <p>2st Number: <input id="number2"></p>
  <button id="multiply">Multiply</button>
  <button id="divide">Divide</button>
  <br>
  <p>The Result Is: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
  $('button').click(function() {
    let choice = this.id;
    let n1 = $('#number1').val();
    let n2 = $('#number2').val();
    let result = 0;
    if(n1 != 0 && n2 != 0){
        if(choice == "multiply"){
          result = n1*n2;
        }else{
          result = n1/n2;
        };
        $('#result').html(result);
    }else{
      $('#result').html("Input empty");
    }
  });

});
```